# Can't make multiple FBSDKGraphRequests

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to read the posts from a Facebook page using the following code:

```
class FacebookGraphAPI {
    class func getPosts(fromPageWithID pageId: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, completion: @escaping ([FacebookPost]?, Error?) -> Void) {
        self.getAccessToken { (accessToken, error) in
            if error != nil {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }

            let params = ["access_token": accessToken, "fields": "created_time,message,story"]

            if let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "\(pageId)/posts", parameters: params) {
                request.start { (connection, result, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        completion(nil, error)
                        return
                    }

                    guard let resultDict = result as? [String: AnyObject],
                        let data = resultDict["data"] as? NSArray
                        else {
                        completion(nil, nil)
                        return
                    }

                    var posts = [FacebookPost]()

                    for item in data {
                        posts.append(FacebookPost(dict: item as! NSDictionary))
                    }

                    completion(posts, nil)
                }
            }

            completion(nil, nil)
        }
    }

    class func getAccessToken(completion: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void) {

        let clientId = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "FacebookAppID") as! String
        let clientSecret = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "FacebookAppSecret") as! String

        let params = ["client_id": clientId, "client_secret": clientSecret, "grant_type": "client_credentials", "fields": "access_token"]

        if let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "oauth/access_token", parameters: params) {
            request.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    completion(nil, error)
                    return
                }

                guard let resultDict = result as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                    completion(nil, nil)
                    return
                }

                let accessToken = resultDict["access_token"] as! String
                completion(accessToken, nil)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Which I then call using e.g. the following:

```
FacebookGraphAPI.getPosts(fromPageWithID: "{page-id}", parameters: ["limit": 5 as AnyObject]) { (posts, error) in
    guard error == nil else { return }

    ...
}
```

The error I'm getting is: `-[_SwiftValue length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` on the second FBSDKGraphRequest start.

I tried removing the first FBSDKGraphRequest and then I at least get a response in the completionHandler. It almost seams as if I can't make more than one FBSDKGraphRequest.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to generate the access token from the first Graph request successfully?

Comment: Yes, without any trouble

Comment: Hmm, suddenly I don't get any response back when trying to get the access token

Comment: Oops, I mistakenly called my method inside a DispatchQueue async block. Now I can successfully get the access token again

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to find the issue, when thinking about the error and remembering that the FBSDKCoreKit framework was written in Objective-C.

All I needed to do was cast `accessToken` inside the parameters array to an `NSString`.

I changed the following:

```
let params = ["access_token": accessToken, "fields": "created_time,message,story"]
```

To:

```
let params = ["access_token": accessToken! as NSString, "fields": "created_time,message,story"]
```